# SQL Server extract the word matching a substring

Tags: sql-server

I need a query, which from the main string, will extract the word(s) that match(es) a list of sub-strings. For example, from the string "I need a password containing no pass-phrase. Please help.", I need a query that will extract the words matching "word" and "phrase". Thus, outcome of the target query will be:
password, pass-phrase

Comment: Show us your table schema, sample data in it, desired output in tabular form and at least some simple query that you tried to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will split sentence into words using space as split value and also split phrases using space. Matching string are found using pathindex. Result rows are join together into one string.

```
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(8000) 

SELECT @Result = COALESCE(@Result + ', ', '') + Sentence.Data
FROM 
(
    SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(8000)') AS Data  
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE('I need a password containing no pass-phrase. Please help.', ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data       
    ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)AS Sentence
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(8000)') AS Data  
    FROM  
    (
         SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE('word phrase', ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data       
) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
) AS Word ON PATINDEX('%'+Word.Data+'%',Sentence.Data )>0

SELECT @Result
```

Result will be "password, pass-phrase."

Answer (score 0):

This would be better done in a programming language that supports REGEX.

If you really have to do this in SQL, you can do it like this:

Use CHARINDEX to find the first occurrence of the first keyword you want to match.

Then use CHARINDEX to find the closest whitespace characters both before and after the keyword.

Then use SUBSTRING to get the characters between those two whitespace characters.

Loop to the next occurrence of the first keyword until you get to the end of the string.

Loop to the next keyword you want to match and repeat the above loop.

If you want to do this inline in a query, you'll want to encapsulate the above in a UDF.